# IE 8 won't display width 100%

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have a very simple code http://jsfiddle.net/MuYVs/
    '

```
    <style type="text/css">

        #header-cont {
            width:100%;
            background:#0080c9;
            background-color:#0080c9;
            height:50px;
            position:absolute;
            top:0px;
            left: 0px;
        }

    </style>
<head>
<body>
    <div id="header-cont"></div>    
</body>'
```

This is fine in Chrome, however, in IE8 the bar will go 98% across and with a little gap at the end. How on earth do I tell IE8 to stop being so silly?

Comment: Do you have a doctype on your page? Can you confirm the rendering mode that IE is using (if it's in Quirks mode, then that's the problem; fix the doctype to solve it).

Comment: @Spudley Thanks for this suggestion, this actually fixed it and avoids unnecessary coding - I can't mark a comment as a correct answer, but if I could yours would be 'correct answer'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the doctype at the beginning:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like default settings the browser has implemented. Have a look at a reset style sheet

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 1):

Try removing any default padding and margins from the body element.

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks, I'm starting to suspect I'll need this styling a lot with IE